# lapply with different optional argument for each element

Tags: r, lapply

The following `lapply` multiply each element in the list by 2

```
lapply(1:5, function(x, y) x * y, y = 2)
```

Is it possible to use `lapply` to specify a different `y` for each element in the list? The following pseudo code is an example:

```
lapply(1:5, function(x, y) x * y, y = 1 if x is odd and = 2 if x is even)
```

Comment: You want mapply not lapply.

Comment: `mapply` is obviously cleaner but you could use `lapply` like a `mapply` if your function's argument is the indices. E.g. `x = 1:5; y = ifelse((x %% 2) == 0, 2, 1); sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[i] * y[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sapply` and `lapply` only allow for one varying argument. If you have multiple you can use `mapply` or `Map`. For example

```
x<-1:5
mapply(function(x, y) x * y, x, 2-(x %% 2))
# [1] 1 4 3 8 5
```

Here we use `2-(1:5 %% 2)` to get a 1 for odds and 2 for evens.